# uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base via AWS-SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

This is an issue I'm having with the fact that after I upgraded to AWS-SDK (instead of aws-s3) with the newer version(s) of paperclip I can no longer call AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection! at all.

Where ever in my code I call

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => '****', :secret_access_key => '***')
```

I get this error...

```
NameError (uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base):
    app/models/asset.rb:28:in `move_upload_from_temp_to_final_resting_place'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yeah, [aws-sdk](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) doesn't have `AWS::S3::Base`.  I think this is the closest equivalent:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => '****', :secret_access_key => '***')
```

Comment: This is correct.  The aws-sdk maintains its own persistent connection pool, no need to explicitly establish a connection.

Comment: I originally fixed it by downgrading all my AWS code to very early versions.  But I was able to upgrade again, using this and get things working nicely with both my aJAX uploader and my EBAY API gem.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It saved a couple of hours of searching :)

Answer (score 2):

As this was the first page that popped up for me on my google search to solve this issue I will comment on how I managed to solve it. Under the AWS SDK 2.0.47

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws/s3'

include AWS::S3

AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
   :access_key_id => '',
   :secret_access_key => ''
)
```

I was simply missing the include AWS::S3. And I suspect many people are running into this issue as I have yet to see a straight foward answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Konstantino solution but, unfortunately, it didn't work for me. using `include AWS::S3` threw the following exception.

`TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)`

This is how I solved the same issue

```
AWS.send(:remove_const, :S3) if AWS::S3.class == Class
require Gem::Specification.find_by_name("aws-s3").gem_dir + "/lib/aws/s3.rb"
```

as I was using `aws-s3`'s modules and methods in another method that was initiated using `delayed_job`, this patch didn't create issue in my case. But this can create issues in another use case as `aws-sdk`'s class is now replaced with `aws-s3`'s module.